# Gaussian Process in single dimension?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, gaussian-process

Suppose that I start with a two-dimensional (zero-mean) Gaussian process; following [Rasmussen and Williams](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf), I denote it by
$$
   f(x, y) \sim \mathcal{GP}(0, k(x, y, x', y')),
$$
where $(x, y) \in \mathbf{R}^2$. I would like to fix the first dimension ($x$), and look at the process only in the second dimension ($y$). For this, let me introduce the following notation.
$$
g_{x}(y) = f(x, y), \\
k_x(y, y') = k(x, y, x, y').
$$
I am now tempted to write
$$
g_{x}(y) \sim \mathcal{GP}(0, k_x(y, y')),
$$
and interpret $g_x(y)$ as a one-dimensional GP. Is this correct? Is this just a consequence of the marginalization property of multivariate Gaussians / Gaussian processes?

This seems like a trivial question, but I'm always afraid of making a basic interpretation mistake somewhere.

Comment: Is this purely for visualisation? It makes more sense to just predict over a linespace where x is constant. If you want to marginalise over x that is different again in which case you would integrate out x from the kernel. If you clarify I'd be happy to help :)

Comment: @j__, what do you mean by "predicting over a linespace where x is a constant?" I guess my question is about whether you can interpret a 2D GP as a collection of (dependent) 1D GPs.

Comment: so what I meant is that you can create lets say a thousand points in the input space with different values of y and constant x and then visualise f(x,y) for these values. You can't simply ignore the first dimension of your data without occurring a lot of extra noise due to the loss in information. Marginalisation means integrating over a particular domain, ie intuitively saying if x was unknown (with a uniform prior measure over the space of x values) what is the resulting f(y). That is what I was referring to in the previous comment but I don't think this is what you want to do.